How can I get a type from a list of Generics
say I have a type like:
T = TypeVar("T")
class MyType(Generic[T]):
   ...

and I have a class:
class Foo:
   def __init__(self, vals: list[MyType]):
       self.vals = vals

But I want to say "The Union of all Generic Args in the list."
So for Foo(vals=[MyType[int], MyType[str], MyType[bool]), I'd like to infer a type hint that is [int, str, bool].
If I do something like this, I still get a mypy error saying: List item 0 has incompatible type "A[int]"; expected "A[int | str]"
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class A(Generic[T]):
    t: T

    def __init__(self, t: T):
        self.t = t

class B(Generic[T]):
    def foo(self, x: list[A[T]]) -> A[T]:
        return x[0]


a1 = A[int](3)
a2 = A[str]('3')
b = B[int | str]().foo([a1, a2])


Have you tried creating a new TypeVar to house your types by creating a  Union of them

the issue is, it says List item 0 has incompatible type "A[int]"; expected "A[int | str]"  so I'd want a TypeVar for the Generic Arguments but I don't think that'll work

I can do something like B[A[int] | A[str]]().foo([A[int](), A[str]()]) where I provide the full type, but it'd be nice to be able to just provide int | str

mypy I think doesn't support inferring a union of types across elements of a list of generics,  a Custom TypeVar with Constraints would be the way forward. How about an helper function to create your instances A, B @Rob. I could draft something for you to look at tho. so have B(Generic[T]) and A(Generic[T]) inherit from the list

list[] is invariant. If you used Sequence, which is covariant, you would see that the type arguments are merged the way you expected. This does not guarantee you have exactly the type you want, however, since type inference rules are pretty much implementation-dependent:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
from collections.abc import Sequence

class MyType[T]: ...

class Foo[T]:
  v: T
  
  def __init__(self, vals: Sequence[MyType[T]]): ...

v = Foo([MyType[int](), MyType[str](), MyType[bool]()]).v
reveal_type(v)  # pyright => int | str
                # mypy    => object

You could write an explicit hint/cast() to workaround this, though that won't be very pretty:
a = cast(
    Sequence[MyType[int] | MyType[str] | MyType[bool]],
    [MyType[int](), MyType[str](), MyType[bool]()]
)

Variadic generics are also not the solution, since there is no way to do transformations on them yet, nor can we collect them into an union.
class Foo[*Ts]:
  v: Union[*Ts]  # This is invalid

  def __init__(self, vals: tuple[Map[MyType, Ts]]): ...  # Also invalid

To add on top of that, there is currently no way to extract a type argument out of an arbitrary parametrized generic type. You might be better off changing your design.

this is interesting, but I think my issue boils down to something like:
list[int] is not valid as list[int | str].  It'd be nice to be able to express this in a TypeVar.

Following our discussion
A customised Constraint Using TypeVar with Constraints
While it might not be your desired outcome using a TypeVar with constraints might be something that would work. However, to directly use int | str without needing to wrap them in A[int] | A[str], We can create some kind of mapping or intermediary function that handles the creation of the A[T] instances.
Even by referring to the mypy_docs
Here is a quote from mypy docs

Explicit types for variables You can override the inferred type of a
variable by using a variable type annotation:
from typing import Union
x: Union[int, str] = 1 Without the type annotation, the type of x
would be just int. We use an annotation to give it a more general type
Union[int, str] (this type means that the value can be either an int
or a str).
The best way to think about this is that the type annotation sets the
type of the variable, not the type of the expression. For instance,
mypy will complain about the following code:
x: Union[int, str] = 1.1  # error: Incompatible types in assignment
# (expression has type "float", variable has type "Union[int, str]")

Which makes using Union impossible, hence why I feel like this approach might work for your case.
Here is a code snippet how it can work
from typing import Generic, List, Type, TypeVar, Union

# your TypeVar with the types you want
T = TypeVar("T", int, str, bool)


# a generic class A that takes T
class A(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T):
        self.value = value


# A class B that accepts a list of A[T] and returns a list of T
class B(Generic[T]):
    def foo(self, x: List[A[T]]) -> List[T]:
        return [item.value for item in x]


# A helper function to create A instances 
def create_instance_A(types: List[Type[T]]) -> List[A[T]]:
    return [A(t()) for t in types]


# For example
b = B[int | str]()
# pass your int and str here, and the helper function will create A[int] and A[str] instances for you
ans = b.foo(create_instance_A([int, str]))

print(ans)  # [0, ''] this assumes your default constructors are int and str)


